# Why does the new gradle test filtering feature not work for my build script?

Tags: testing, gradle, filtering

I am working on a "project" that has the following structure:

```
proj
  - dbfit-junit/module
    - db1
    - db2
```

To provide some background information: All of these "modules" (db1, db2) have JUnit tests that use the FitNesseRunner to integrate them in Bamboo.

My gradle script looks like following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files(fileTree("lib"))
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}

ext {
    dbFitModuleDir = file("dbfit-junit/module")
    dbFitModules = dbFitModuleDir.listFiles({f -> f.isDirectory()} as java.io.FileFilter).collect{it.name}
}

dbFitModules.each { module ->
    sourceSets.create("${module}SourceSet") {
        java.srcDir new File(dbFitModuleDir, module)
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
        runtimeClasspath = output + sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
    }

    task "dbFit${module.capitalize()}"(type: Test) {
        testClassesDir = sourceSets."${module}SourceSet".output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets."${module}SourceSet".runtimeClasspath
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}
```

So far everything works as expected and I am able to dynamically create the module specific gradle tasks and to execute the tests.

Nevertheless one thing is not working at all for me. I've learned from [Gralde release notes 1.10](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.10/release-notes.html#executing-specific-tests-from-the-command-line) that there is a new feature called "test filtering" but it does not affect any of the tasks I am calling from commandline (e.g. gradlew dbFitDb1 --tests *DataIntegrity).

Although I apply the --tests filter all of my tests are executed. Thus I am wondering if there is sth. wrong with my script or if I have to enable test filtering in general etc.

Thx for any hints!

Comment: It should just work. Perhaps try with a simple test project first. Another thing you can try is to put the naming pattern in quotes.

Comment: Hi @PeterNiederwieser, As it looks like, `@RunsWith` annotation is the reason for filters not working. When I remove the `@RunsWith` annotation the filter works. I added a sample project to github in case you wanna have a look https://github.com/u6f6o/fakeDbFit.git

Comment: Initially I thought that the `FitnesseSuite.class` runner causes this error but it also does not work with the `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class`

Comment: Thanks. We've just hit a similar issue in our own build. Perhaps it's a bug in the new `--tests` feature. We'll investigate. For the time being, you can always use the old `-DtestTaskName.single=*DataIntegrity` instead. (Depending on your shell, you may have to quote the whole argument.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that the filters do not work if you add a @RunWith annotation to your JUnit tests. The guys from Gradle aknowledged this issue and will fix it soon. In the meantime I'll use "test.single" to make it work.

https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3112

Comment: Do you have a link to the Gradle bug report?